# Android Studio 3 gradle sync issue

Tags: android

i'm working on a project with Android Studio but i have no idea about the Android Studio.. 
can't solve the gradle sync error for hours. my build.gradle is like this: (not the wrong one, it's the app build.gradle)

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.kofax.sdk.samples.easysnap'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}

dependencies {

    def sdkRef

    project.getRootProject().allprojects.each { proj ->
        if (proj.name.toLowerCase().equals('sdk')) {
            sdkRef = proj;
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (sdkRef) {
        println "SDK present in project; using project reference as dependency"
        compile sdkRef
    } else {
        println "SDK is not present in project; dependency reference"

        repositories {
            flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
        }

        compile (name: 'sdk-release', ext: 'aar')
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

i tried to clean project it's not about it, is it about the plugins or the missing filesor libs? 
i've keep getting this error:

> Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
>
> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Please help...

Comment: if you are using android studio 3.0 then the gradle plugin version is 3.0.0 ('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
) and distributionUrl is \
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work on Android Studio 3.0. Change "2.0.0" to "3.0.0" in your project gradle :

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

In your gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

In your app gradle : "compile" become "implementation" :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
}
```

You should read that :

> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: done these solved the error, thanks a lot! but now i'm getting this: _Error:Failed to resolve: :sdk-release:_
it's in project->libs. why can't solve?

Comment: Maybe change compile (name: 'sdk-release', ext: 'aar') to implementation (name: 'sdk-release', ext: 'aar')
Take a look on this :https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#local_jars

Answer (score 0):

Android plugin 3.0.0 requires Gradle version 4.1 or higher. If you're opening an existing project using Android Studio 3.0 or later, follow the prompts to automatically update an existing project to the compatible version of Gradle.

To update Gradle manually, edit the URL in *gradle-wrapper.properties* to the following: `distributionUrl=\https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

And include the maven repo and change the plugin version in your **project-level** *build.gradle* file as follows:

```
buildscript {

        repositories {
            ...
            // You need to add the following repository to download the
            // new plugin.
            google()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        }
    }
```