# "Failed to resolve :sdk-release: " which is aar file

Tags: android, sdk

i asked a question before about my project and still need a help..

[Android Studio 3 gradle sync issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991467/android-studio-3-gradle-sync-issue/46991737?noredirect=1#comment80930569_46991737)

now i have another problem which i can't figure out. when i try to build my project, i get this error:

> Error:Failed to resolve: :sdk-release:

my ***sdk-release.aar*** file is in **projectFolder>libs>aar** and also **sdk-release** folder

what is that error and how can i solve this?

my ***build.gradle*** code is like this now

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.kofax.sdk.samples.easysnap'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}

dependencies {

    def sdkRef

    project.getRootProject().allprojects.each { proj ->
        if (proj.name.toLowerCase().equals('sdk')) {
            sdkRef = proj;
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (sdkRef) {
        println "SDK present in project; using project reference as dependency"
        compile sdkRef
    } else {
        println "SDK is not present in project; dependency reference"

        repositories {
            flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
        }

        implementation (name: 'sdk-release', ext: 'aar')
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

}
```

Answer (score -1):

change the code:

```
implementation (name: 'sdk-release', ext: 'aar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

to

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
```

or

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
```